# Branch.io Deeplink is opening the deep link every time the app is launched

Tags: ios, objective-c, branch.io

I have used Branch.io for creating deeplink for my app. But it's redirecting me to the deep link controller every time app is launched.

I have used following code in - `(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions`

```
Branch *branch = [Branch getInstance];

HomeDetailsViewController *controller = (HomeDetailsViewController*)[[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"HomeDetailsViewControllerID"];

 [branch registerDeepLinkController:controller forKey:@"bucketId"];
 [branch initSessionWithLaunchOptions:launchOptions automaticallyDisplayDeepLinkController:YES];
```

..

```
// Respond to Universal Links - Branch io
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application continueUserActivity:(NSUserActivity *)userActivity restorationHandler:(void (^)(NSArray *restorableObjects))restorationHandler {
    BOOL handledByBranch = [[Branch getInstance] continueUserActivity:userActivity];

    return handledByBranch;
}

-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app openURL:(NSURL *)url options:(NSDictionary *)options NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(9_0) {

    [[Branch getInstance] handleDeepLink:url];

     [self application:app
        processOpenURLAction:url
           sourceApplication:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey]
                  annotation:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey]
                  iosVersion:9];

    return YES;
}



-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {
    [[Branch getInstance] handleDeepLink:url];

     [self application:application
        processOpenURLAction:url
           sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                  annotation:annotation
                  iosVersion:8];

    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not call `instantiateViewController...` from

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

According to their [docs](https://dev.branch.io/getting-started/sdk-integration-guide/#configure-xcode-project), you should use the following code instead:

```
Branch *branch = [Branch getInstance];
[branch initSessionWithLaunchOptions:launchOptions andRegisterDeepLinkHandler:^(NSDictionary *params, NSError *error) {
    if (!error && params) {
        // params are the deep linked params associated with the link that the user clicked -> was re-directed to this app
        // params will be empty if no data found
        // ... insert custom logic here ...
        NSLog(@"params: %@", params.description);
    }
}];
```

Comment: Yeah I also Implemented this code but it was also returning yes for the param 'clicked_branch_link' even when the link was not clicked. I think it saves the value somewhere for it's preference. But when I tested it through test flight it was working fine.

Comment: Alex from Branch.io here: if you were testing extensively, it's possible you had multiple link clicks queued up for that device ID, and the SDK just needed to clear them sequentially. If you continue to have issues, let me know!

Comment: I have the same issue, how can I clean up ?  @AlexBauer